# RSQLite parametrized query

Tags: r, rsqlite

I am using the library `RSQLite` and I am struggling to understand how to use the `params` argument of the `dbGetQuery()` function.

Following the documentation, I am able to parametrize the WHERE statement of the query, but I am unable to do the same for the table name or for the columns.

```
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = ?", params = list(1:8))

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM ?", params = list("mtcars"))
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT ? FROM mtcars", params = list("cyl"))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

What is wrong with the last two queries?
I know it is possible to use different approaches (`paste()`, `glue::glue()`, etc.), just wanted to understand the problem.

Thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure this question isn't really related to R or RSQLite; it's an SQLite question.  Parameters can be used in the underlying C interface for values, not for arbitrary parts of SQL query expressions.

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation (march 2023), you can send parametrized sql queries to sqlite using the ":x" notation rather than the standard SQL "?" one

he is an example:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = ?", params = list(1:8))
```

and the link
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html

look for "queries"